# general approaches in learning the subtle (or not so subtle) differences of words

Tags: differences, synonyms

What is the best way to learn the subtle (or not so subtle) difference in words?

For example, most dictionaries will tell me that both 'replete with' and 'fraught with' mean 'full of.'  But are they really the same?

Another example is the question I asked before about 'subside' and 'dissipate.' I looked up a few dictionaries but could not find a ton of helpful information, but people here are able to give very in-depth answers.

I am just wondering how people get the subtle shades of the meanings and how do I get those.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why does this question have the `single-word-requests` tag applied to it?

Comment: Because it is about the general approaches to distinguishing the meanings of similar single words.

Comment: The tag means that a single word will answer your question. From its description: "This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning." If the tag is correct, the answer you accepted did not provide a single word as an answer. I've modified the tags to what I think is closer to what you'd actually intended.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Not appropriate for this site

Comment: I am curious why you think this way. Is it because the question is general? I think it pays to have a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many, if not most of the contributors to English Language and Usage are native speakers so we have spent a lifetime acquiring our vocabularies.

As to how we learn the subtleties of meaning one of the ways is by asking the people from whom we learned them, often our parents, but also from reading and hearing the words in context.

For instance we know that "replete with" means "full of" literally in the sense of being full of food but sometimes means other things metaphorically while "fraught with" means "full of" in the sense of being encumbered because we have read many sentences using both words where the context is clear. We know that a bucket cannot be either "fraught" with water or "replete" with water because we have not read sentences with that construction. If we read one we would know that its use was either erroneous or poetic.

The way you, as a student of English, can learn these subtleties is to read and listen to as much good English as you can and, when you find a word you either do not recognise or of the subtle meaning of which you are unsure, to think about it and compare it with other contexts in which you seen the same word.

Comment: One problem with this approach is that it is very difficult to encounter examples for less frequently used words. Take the instance of replete vs fraught. If I look at the Corpus of Contemporary American English (https://www.english-corpora.org), replete occurs 1,196 times, fraught  1,728 times, and, in comparison, "full" 113,335 times!  Do you have any suggestions on what to read?

Comment: @TomBennett It depends to some extent on how good you are at reading English. You should try to read magazines, newspapers and books which are at, or just above, the level you find easy to read. It also depends on your interests, if you are keen on politics, for example, you would choose different publications from the ones you would choose if you preferred science or the arts. In a British context and you can read well enough you might like The Times, and The Guardian newspapers. Also modern fiction by writers like John le Carre and Tom Sharpe might be good. Read as widely as you can.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I read NYT, WSJ, financial times, HBR, the New Yorker, and a ton of nonfiction books and blogs. I don't read fictions due to time constraint. I am finding very few word usages on the more complex words. I think what I read is business/news heavy and maybe that is why I am not finding new word usages. More suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: @TomBennett Are you reading the comment pieces, features and editorials or only the factual reports? The more in-depth pieces, paticulary foreatures, are often written in a slightly more conversational style.

Comment: I try to read all the articles when I have time, but sometimes don't have time for the longer pieces.